# Composite PK with JPA in ORACLE gives ORA-00904 error

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, composite-primary-key

I have to map a composite PK with JPA in an Oracle DB.

I've followed other SO questions with relation to this [tutorial](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-composite-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) but I'm still getting the following error:

`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "COMPOSITEI0_"."NAME_1": Invalid Identifier` (where NAME_1 relates to the name of one of the columns which are part of the PK)

This is my entity (real names not mentioned for data protection reasons):

```
  @Entity
@Table(schema = "SCHEMA", name = "TABLE")
public class CompositeIdEntity {

  @Column(name = "NAME1")
  private String name1;

  @Column(name = "NAME2")
  private String name2;

  @Column(name = "NAME3")
  private String name3;



  @EmbeddedId
  CompositePrimaryKeyTableEmbeddable id;


  public CompositePrimaryKeyTableEmbeddable getId() {

    return this.id;
  }

      public void setId(CompositePrimaryKeyTableEmbeddable id) {

        this.id = id;
      }

  // other getters and setters
```

My @Embeddable id class:

```
@Embeddable
public class CompositePrimaryKeyTableEmbeddable implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="name1")
    private String name1;

    @Column(name="name2")
    private String name2;

    public CompositePrimaryKeyTableEmbeddable() {
        super();
    }

    public CompositePrimaryKeyTableEmbeddable(String name1, String name2) {
        this.name1 = name1;
        this.name2 = name2;
    }
```

My @Repository:

```
 @Repository
public interface CompositeIdDao extends JpaRepository<CompositeIdEntity, CompositePrimaryKeyTableEmbeddable> {

}
```

And finally call to the DB, which only returns null because it's just a test to see if it all works together:

```
public CompositeIdEto saveCompositeId() {

    CompositeIdEntity compositeIdEto = new CompositeIdEntity();
    compositeIdEto.setname3("New");
    compositeIdEto.setId(new CompositePrimaryKeyTableEmbeddable("ERR", "ER"));

    this.compositeIdDao.save(compositeIdEto);

    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are duplicating the `name1` and `name2` columns by declaring them once
in the entity itself and later in the embeddable.

You seem to only need the id embeddable and the `name3` declaration in the entity:

```
   @Entity
   @Table(schema = "SCHEMA", name = "TABLE")
   public class CompositeIdEntity {

   @EmbeddedId
   CompositePrimaryKeyTableEmbeddable id;

   @Column(name = "NAME3")
   private String name3;
```

Comment: Yep, at some point during my testing, ORACLE gave me a more accurate message error and I could see that I was duplicating, that did the trick, thanks!